# Card of Decks Making a deal of specific size C Language

Tags: c

Hello Everyone I am having a problem here.

My Problem is that I would like a program that makes a normal deck of cards,shuffles and randomly deal 9 hands(two cards)then 3 cards and 1 card and then 1 more card, then calculate how often you get a pocket pair(two cards of the same rank), this must be done through trial and error and tracking statistics while working. the pocket pair is from the 9 hands.

Now for this purpose Here what I have done till now 
1. Create a deck of 52 Cards
2. Shuffling a deck 
3. Dealing a card

Now I am having a problem in my code it is showing error. What i want is that to deal 9 hands (two cards) I just want to deal (Inner loop to be of size 2 ) for 3 cards (Inner loop to be of size 3) and to deal one (Inner loop of size 1 ) But Its showing error that "too many arguments in deal".

Here's the code

```
/* Fig. 10.3: cardShuffle.c
The card shuffling and dealing program using structures */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* card structure definition */               
struct card {                                 
   const char *face; /* define pointer face */
   const char *suit; /* define pointer suit */
}; /* end structure card */                   

typedef struct card Card; /* new type name for struct card */

/* prototypes */
void fillDeck( Card * const wDeck, const char * wFace[], 
   const char * wSuit[] );
void shuffle( Card * const wDeck );
void deal( const Card * const wDeck );

int main( void )
{ 
   Card deck[ 52 ]; /* define array of Cards */

   /* initialize array of pointers */
   const char *face[] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
      "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
      "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

   /* initialize array of pointers */
   const char *suit[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

   srand( time( NULL ) ); /* randomize */

   fillDeck( deck, face, suit ); /* load the deck with Cards */
   shuffle( deck ); /* put Cards in random order */
   deal( deck, 2); /* deal all 52 Cards */

   return 0; /* indicates successful termination */

} /* end main */

/* place strings into Card structures */
void fillDeck( Card * const wDeck, const char * wFace[], 
   const char * wSuit[] )
{ 
   int i; /* counter */

   /* loop through wDeck */
   for ( i = 0; i <= 51; i++ ) { 
      wDeck[ i ].face = wFace[ i % 13 ];
      wDeck[ i ].suit = wSuit[ i / 13 ];
   } /* end for */

} /* end function fillDeck */

/* shuffle cards */
void shuffle( Card * const wDeck )
{ 
   int i;     /* counter */
   int j;     /* variable to hold random value between 0 - 51 */
   Card temp; /* define temporary structure for swapping Cards */

   /* loop through wDeck randomly swapping Cards */
   for ( i = 0; i <= 51; i++ ) { 
      j = rand() % 52;
      temp = wDeck[ i ];      
      wDeck[ i ] = wDeck[ j ];
      wDeck[ j ] = temp;      
   } /* end for */

} /* end function shuffle */

/* deal cards */
void deal( const Card * const wDeck , int size)
{ 
   int i; /* counter */

   /* loop through wDeck */
   for ( i = 0; i <= size; i++ ) {
      printf( "%5s of %-8s%c", wDeck[ i ].face, wDeck[ i ].suit,( i + 1 ) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n' );
   } /* end for */

} /* end function deal */
```

Please Tell me What is the problem how it can be solved. and share your logic how main problem can be achieved.  Thanks

Comment: too many arguments to function 'deal'

Comment: So what do you understand from this error?

Comment: that deal is having too many arguments lol but the problem is how do I solve it @EugeneSh.

Comment: A simple search on `deal` over the code reveals the source of the problem. Anyway, @Caleb have just done it for you.

Comment: I've solved the error but the thing is @Eugene Sh. that my main problem was to deal with the hands and then check whether they have same ranks or not , If they have same ranks Then Its a pocket pair ... Now I want to calculate the Odds of having a Pocket Pair ... After successfully dealing nine hands then 3 then 1 and 1 again then 9 again ... After that How many chances of Pocket Pair will it be there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prototype for `deal`:

```
void deal( const Card * const wDeck );
```

doesn't match the implementation:

```
void deal( const Card * const wDeck , int size)
```

or the way you call it:

```
deal( deck, 2);
```

Fix the prototype and the error should disappear.

Comment: running but deck is not dealing with the specific size of hand. Hey @Caleb I know am a newbie in C , but is their any other way out to do what I asked earlier.

Comment: You asked about a specific problem, and it sounds like my answer above solved the problem. You said that you want to collect your data by actually simulating the hands, so I'm not sure what "other way" you're asking about. There are other ways to calculate the probability of a pocket pair, of course, but that's pretty well beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: What will be that probability I will try it myself but Where should I start?

Comment: Probability is the number of desired outcomes divided by the number of possible outcomes, right? So you need to count or calculate the number of hands that include a pocket pair and divide by the total number of hands. But we're digressing into applied math here... if this is for a class, your instructor or TA can help you far better than I can.

Comment: I understand what probability is, I don't know Poker. and I guess you are right that I have to calculate the number of hands that include a pocket pair and divide the total number of hands.

Comment: In the meantime, if the answer above solved the immediate problem, please accept it so that your question doesn't appear unanswered.

Comment: Done @Caleb ... but I need to understand this thing How to do that ? How to calculate odds. Can you share any resources or anything which can be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94841/discussion-between-umair-xajid-and-caleb).